# How to delete lines with NaN after the 3rd columns only,

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I opened a CSV with Pandas DataFrame and I want to delete lines with NaN, only after the 3rd column.

Ex:

| Country Name | Country Code | Series | 1970 | 1980 | 1990 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | FR | AFT32 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Brasil | BR | AFT33 | NaN | 34 | NaN |
| Spain | SP | AFT34 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Portugal | PT | AFT35 | 27 | NaN | 86 |
| Italy | IT | AFT36 | NaN | NaN | 99 |

For this example, I only want deletes lines France and Spain because they have just NaN after the 3rd column.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna

Answer (score 0):

Specify a list of column names and use `pandas.DataFrame.dropna()`:

```py
df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['1970', '1980', '1990'], inplace=True)
```